# Redshift DISTKEY / SORTKEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-redshift

I have a very technical question about how Redshift deals with `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY` internally in order to fulfill the storing tier and the query execution demands. I have read this amazing [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-distribution-styles-and-distribution-keys/) that explains very well what means each of these regarding the table design.

My question is let's suppose I have a table *A* with three columns:

```
CREATE TABLE (
orderdate timestamp distkey,
product_id varchar(50),
product_name varchar(250)
) SORTKEY (product_id)
```

Now, we know that Redshift is a columnar approach DB optimized for data warehousing. In my example is clear that probably the way how the data will be distributed across the slices for the computing nodes is based on the `DISTKEY` orderdate. But, what happens with the column `product_id` and `product_name` ? are these distributed along with `orderdate` on the same slice and then when I execute a query Redshift uses the zone maps based on my `SORTKEY` to point out the zone of the column that has the data and retrieve it?

If Redshift is a columnar approach then shouldn't each column has a different way to be stored? or what this really means is that: Based on a column wisely picked out among all, the whole columns are going to be stored on the same slice along with the `DISTKEY` and then to guarantee the performance the user can even focus the query on a specific zone to pull the required data. So I might overall something like:

> `DISTKEY` storage tier  and `SORTKEY` query execution behave

Now if I use a `DISTKEY` so my data is stored based that punctual column order, so if later on, I use a  `SORTKEY` the other for my `DISTKEY` can't be changed or altered so how this works?

So sorry folks if I'm so wrong but I need to understand well how this architecture drive the data internally. Thanks so much

**Update**

Based on the @JoeHarris post answering this question I have tried to picture how the data perhaps look stored.

The first level of distribution is my `DISTKEY` (dates are not good but just to follow with the same example) and then internally redshift sorts by my `SORTKEY`, giving something like:

[image]

thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `DISTKEY` distributes **rows** amongst slices.

In your example, all rows with a given `orderdate` would be located in the same slice. That means that **all columns for those rows** are in that slice.

If two tables have the same DISTKEY, then all rows in *both tables* with the same value for the DISTKEY column will be located on the same slice.

By the way, dates and timestamps are not good candidates for DISTKEY because they are very rarely used in a `JOIN`. Unique identifiers like `product_id` would make a better DISTKEY. The general rule is to use a column that appears in the most/biggest JOINs.

The `SORTKEY` determines how the rows are ordered within the table. For the rows stored on each slice, they are stored in SORTKEY order. Data for each column is stored in separate blocks (and most likely each column uses many blocks), but within the column blocks the rows are in the same order.

For example, if a table has three columns, it will occupy at least three blocks per slice (one for each column). Within those column blocks, the rows are all in the same order.

Each block also has a min and max value ("Zone Maps"), making it very easy for Redshift to 'skip over' blocks that do not contain a desired value. This greatly speeds performance because disk access is the slowest part of an operation.

Comment: @JoeHarris thanks so much for what a wonderful explanation. I have tried to picture how this looks internally so I would like to know your thoughts. thanks

Comment: @AndresUrregoAngel Your picture should actually show the dates distributed across several slices, with all rows for a given date being stored in the same slice. Then, within a slice, the rows are sorted by the SORTKEY.

Comment: @JohnRotensteinhow Redshift might acts if I have a very basic cluster with one compute node with only 2 slices? how it know how distributed then if every date is going to a different slice?

Comment: The value in the DISTKEY column is hashed and values are distributed based on the hash. (This is how different tables can co-locate data by simply having DISTKEY columns with the same data.) The hash value is then used to distribute the data over any available slices. A 2-slice cluster would divide the hash by 2. A 4-slice cluster would divide the hash by 4 etc. That is why columns with limited values (eg `Male` and `Female`) are not good choices for DISTKEY because with only two values it would only use two slices.